# s3 / php script looping (strace)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Anyone using the following php S3 client library?

http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

It's been working fine for me for a few days, just noticed that a script I have in place now just ends up hanging.

Running this through strace, I see something like:

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLHUP}])
```

Looking at what's running, I see that it's not even getting to the point where it makes the curl call.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more debugging, I found it's giving me the following:

S3::putObject(): [RequestTimeout] Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.

Comment: (Though, this doesn't always happen, first time I noticed it the script was running for 13 hours!)

Comment: I've been usign it for a while and there doesn't seem to be any problem on my end. Could you post some of your code?

Comment: Here's my entire script, I just pass in the file to upload (sorry, not sure how to make code appear correctly in the comments!):

    

    $AMAZON_KEY = "xxxx";
    $AMAZON_PRIVATE_KEY = "xxxx";
    $AMAZON_BUCKET = "xx_backups";

    require_once("S3.php");


    $fullpath_file = $argv[1];
    $filename = basename($argv[1]);

    $s3 = new S3($AMAZON_KEY, $AMAZON_PRIVATE_KEY, false);
    $s3->putObject($s3->inputFile($fullpath_file, false), $AMAZON_BUCKET, $filename);

Comment: Actually, not sure about if it gets to the curl call.  Oddly, when it does work, I do a "ps aux | grep curl" and I get no results, yet the transfer succeeds.  Still, I get this "poll" loop on occasion, running for hours.  For now, I'll try to put a curl timeout, and try looping a couple times on failure, hopefully that serves as a workaround.